# How to dismiss a dialog containing a WebView from the WebView class

Tags: android, dialog, webview

I am trying to make webview as a dialog in my android app, and close it when I load needed webpage. dialog opens on button click in activity, and if close dialog just after opening(in activity), it's work, but in my WebViewClient it always crash. dialog create:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
         switch (id) {
         case 1:
             dialog = new Dialog(this);
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.webviewl);
             dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
             webview = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.vkWebView);
             webview.setWebViewClient(wvClforVK);
             webview.loadUrl(url);
         webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
         return dialog;
         default:
         return super.onCreateDialog(id);
            }
    }   
    public void showVKDialog(){
         dialog = new Dialog(this);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.webviewl);
         dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
         webview = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.vkWebView);
         webview.setWebViewClient(wvClforVK);
         webview.loadUrl(url);
         dialog.show();
    }
public void dismissDialog(){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

open on button

```
showDialog(1);
```

in WebViewClass:

```
//code
    @Override
            public void onPageFinished (WebView webview, String url){
        //lalala some kind of my perfect code.... :)

 Activity myActivity = new Activity();
             myActivity.dismissDialog();
```

web view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/vkWebView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     Activity myActivity = new Activity();
     myActivity.dismissDialog();
```

You cannot simply instantiate a new Activity and call dissmissDialog(); on it. You have to call it on the Activity instance you used to open the dialog from. So I guess you have to pass the Activity into your WebView class and call dissmissDialog() on it.